# how to give Odoo xpath in t-attf-id

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

How to give **xpath** in this position inside.

```
<div t-attf-id="o_payment_form_acq_{{acq.id}}" t-attf-class="hidden {{'panel-footer' if acq.save_token == 'ask' else ''}}">
```

I tried the following but it gives an error:

```
<template id="stripe_form_type" inherit_id="payment.payment_tokens_list">
<xpath expr="//div[hasid('o_payment_form_acq_{{acq.id}}')]" position="after">
<div>hello</div>
</xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: Because the div you are looking for has no a_b class

Comment: I edit my question. please, see the edit one.. @TadeuszKarpinski

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
<template id="stripe_form_type" inherit_id="payment.payment_tokens_list">
   <xpath expr="//div[@t-attf-id='o_payment_form_acq_{{acq.id}}']" position="after">
      <div>hello</div>
   </xpath> 
</template>
```

When it is hard to get element I use relative path. The element you want to get contains inout element.

```
                <div t-attf-id="o_payment_form_acq_{{acq.id}}" t-attf-class="hidden {{'panel-footer' if acq.save_token == 'ask' else ''}}">
                    <label t-if="acq.save_token == 'ask'"><input type="checkbox" name="o_payment_form_save_token" data-remove-me=""/> Save my payment data</label>
                </div>
```

So you can get it using this code

```
<template id="stripe_form_type" inherit_id="payment.payment_tokens_list">
   <xpath expr="//input[@name='o_payment_form_save_token']/.." position="after">
      <div>hello</div>
   </xpath> 
</template>
```